# How to know which octant in a circle point lies in?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am doing an assignment in windows desktop application and i am trying to write a function to check where the point that the user clicked on using WM_RBUTTONDOWN lies inside my drawn circle.

So the function takes the center of the circle and the point that the user clicked on and in each condition it checks the quadrant and if x1 > y1 then the point lies in the bottom half of the quadrant, if not then it's the upper half, but apparently this is wrong? because it never outputs 2 or 3 o 6 or 7 in my code and i dont know why

```
int checkOctant(int xc, int yc, int x1, int y1) {

    //check which octant the user clicked on (going anti-clockwise)
    if (x1 > xc && y1  < yc && abs(x1) > abs(y1)) return 1;
    if (x1 > xc && y1  < yc && abs(x1) < abs(y1)) return 2;

    if (x1 < xc && y1 < yc && abs(x1) < abs(y1)) return 3;
    if (x1 < xc && y1 < yc && abs(x1) > abs(y1)) return 4;

    if (x1 < xc && y1 > yc && abs(x1) > abs(y1)) return 5;
    if (x1 < xc && y1 > yc && abs(x1) < abs(y1)) return 6;

    if (x1 > xc && y1 > yc && abs(x1) < abs(y1)) return 7;
    if (x1 > xc && y1 > yc && abs(x1) > abs(y1)) return 8;
  
}
```

Comment: I think it is to check the degree at which the point lies compared to the x-axis or y-axis. If `abs(x1)` is greater than `abs(y1)`, then the clicked point is more closer to the x-axis then the y-axis.

Comment: `if (x1 > xc && y1  < yc && abs(x1 - xc) > abs(y1 - yc))`

Comment: A note about style, some boolean constants (e.g. `const bool xAbove = x1 > xc`) would make it clearer and prevent typos.